# How to wrap checkbox widget with ValueListenableBuilder widget?

Tags: flutter, checkbox, setstate

Checkbox(
value: datas[i]["check"],
onChanged: (bool newValue) => setState((){
*Array data in looping*
datas[i]["check"] = !datas[i]["check"];
}),
),

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Checkbox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html) together with [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) as shown below:

Given that you have a [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) variable, `_checkboxState` to hold your `Checkbox` state:

```
final ValueNotifier<bool> _checkboxState = ValueNotifier<bool>(false); //Initialized to false
```

You can wrap the `Checkbox` widget with `ValueListenableBuilder` and get rid of the `setState` method and set the `ValueNotifier` variable value:

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: _checkboxState,
      builder: (BuildContext context, dynamic value, Widget child) {
        return Checkbox(
          value: _checkboxState.value,
          onChanged: (newCheckboxState) {
            _checkboxState.value = newCheckboxState;
          },
        );
      },
    ),
```